# AppleScript to close "About this Mac" window

Tags: macos, applescript

How could I use AppleScript code to close the window named "About this Mac" (A propos de ce Mac in French). I need an AppleScript for this because I use Dragon Dictate 3 commands. I am handicapped and I don't manage to use any keyboard or mouse. Only Voice and edited commands.

I tried Command+W shortcut but it didn't work for this window. It works for all other Finder windows except this one.

Comment: I tried this code but it doesn't work...set _dictateApp to (name of current application)
tell application "Finder"
      close front window
end tell

Comment: That's weird, Command + W works here.

Comment: On my mac it doesnt because the window is not selected, inactive. I need to click on it to use Command W.

Comment: Oh yeah… sorry. Here's a tip. The About My Mac window is managed by the process `loginwindow`. I don't know if this piece of info helps, but if it does, tell me.

Comment: Ok could you give me an example because I am a very beginner of using applescript. Thanks ?

Comment: thanks to the poster for this code, which works like a charm !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The window is shown by the loginwindow process, and you can close it by clicking the close button:

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "loginwindow"
    click button 1 of window 1 -- or window "About This Mac"
end tell
```

`close window 1` didn't work.